# Распознавание чисел с помощью нейросетей

Tags: графика, библиотеки, c++, visual-studio

Всем доброго времени суток! Пишу курсовую работу по программированию. Требуется написать программу, которая бы распознавала десятичный числа.

На данный момент написал простенькую реализацию самообучающейся нейронной сети, которая на вход получает массив из 15 целочисленных цифр (1 и 0 - соответствующие определенной цифре). Но как вы понимаете, этого далеко недостаточно.

Сейчас думаю, как написать программу, которая будет работать непосредственно с изображением. Так вот вопросы:

1. Работаю я в Visual Studio на языке C++. Какую библиотеку лучше выбрать, для работы с графикой?
2. С форматом какого изображения начать, чтобы было проще обрабатывать картинку?
3. Может, кто-то владеет подобным опытом или добротным контентом по этой теме и даст пару полезных советов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имхо winforms имеют убогий дизайн. Попробуйте qt или wxwidgets, я бы рекомендовал второе (проще, и можно сразу скачать сборку под VS компиляторы). В идеале Вам нужно загуглить классификационные нейронные сети, а затем реализацию хоть какой-то. Вам понадобится 10 выходных нейронов (0-9) и N входных, где в лучшем случае N - количество пикселей картинки. Для простоты я бы взял 16х32, и работал с такими исходными данными (т.е. чернобелыми картинками такого размера).

Для работы с любыми картинками подойдет задача перевода любой картинки в картинку размером 16х32. Она тоже не тривиальна, и лучше взяться за нее, если уже решите эту.
Хорошо, если найдете хорошую классифицирующую сеть в open source. Такие точно есть, когда-то я товарищу делал диплом и находил. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед.
Если же реализация самой нейронной сети - и есть суть задачи, то я уверен, Вы получите высший балл, реализовав расчеты на видеопроцессорах (с помощью CUDA). Не сложно, но лучшей пыли в глаза преподу не придумать. И работать будет эффективнее.

Comment: Спасибо, выбрал Qt и разрешение 16X32.
Собираюсь сделать следующим образом:
1) Превратить картинку в черно-белую
2) Найти то место, где находится цифра
3) Взять именно ту область изображение
4) Привести ее к формату 16X32 и потом уже распознавать...
Может у вас еще имеется какая-либо информация по вышеперечисленному?
Не отказался бы от еще одного хорошего совета!

Comment: Мне кажется, все эти задачи очень сложные. Поиск области с цифрой, перевод картинки в черно-белую, перевод формата. Конечно, если Вы найдете готовые решения для этих задач - хорошо, но если не найдете, лучше не беритесь решать это вручную. Для курсовой хорошей темой было бы просто уже иметь картинку 16х32 чернобелую, и ее распознавать. А когда это получится, наращивать остальные шаги.
Для классификации попробуйте сети Хюмминга. В сети есть имплементации достойные.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен типовой интерфейс то:

1. winforms.
2. bmp.
3. google.

Если что-то нестандартное, то все, что вы хотите, есть в opengl.